# Looking for a specific old-school "Flying Dot Terrain" screensaver

Tags: screensaver

I've scoured the internet but I can't seem to find the screen saver I'm thinking of. If memory serves, I last saw it about ~15~ nope 25 (updated) years ago in grade-school on our Apple computers.

It was animated from a bird's-eye-view, flying over a 3D terrain composed of colored dots (green dots for grass, blue for water, etc).  The closest thing I can find that resembles what I'm talking about is this image:

[image]

I've always remembered the way I felt when I saw it, but haven't seen it since that day.  Does anybody have any idea what I'm talking about or where I can find that screensaver?

Comment: I didn't find anything with a few searches in Google that seemed to fit your description, but there is a web site that claims to provide many Apple-style screen savers.  Maybe you can spot it (or something similar) there?  http://free-apple-style-screensaver.winsite.com/

Comment: @Randolf Richardson - That's "Apple-style," not Apple-compatible. Follow the link on any screensaver on that page and it will say "Runs on:Win95, Win98, WinME, WinXP, Windows2000, Windows2003, Windows Vista…".

Comment: @Dori:  Please read my entire comment, which includes "Maybe you can spot it (or something similar) there?"  At the very least, this may be help someone else recognize it and get to an actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

[After Dark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Dark_(software)) -- of "Flying Toasters" and "Starry Night" fame -- was the most popular screen saver package on the Mac in the early to mid 90's. You might be thinking of the "Mountains" module, but I can't find a screenshot or video of it to double-check.

Comment: I think this is as good as it will get.  Once I find a copy of that module, I'll update this post.  Thanks for taking the time!